# Installation error: Unknown failure

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed the ADT 23.04 plugin into my eclipse and Android SDK of the same version.
I am able to successfully start the AVD but when I try start the AVD a black black screen appears without and remains for many minutes without anything happening and then when I try to run the project on the AVD,I get the following error log:

```
[2014-12-15 23:05:53 - MyApp] ------------------------------
[2014-12-15 23:05:54 - MyApp] Android Launch!
[2014-12-15 23:05:54 - MyApp] adb is running normally.
[2014-12-15 23:05:54 - MyApp] Performing com.example.myapp.ExampleActivity activity launch
[2014-12-15 23:05:54 - MyApp] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Myavd2' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2014-12-15 23:05:54 - MyApp] Uploading MyApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-12-15 23:05:56 - MyApp] Installing MyApp.apk...
[2014-12-15 23:06:05 - MyApp] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2014-12-15 23:06:05 - MyApp] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-12-15 23:06:06 - MyApp] Launch canceled!
```

Below is the screenshot of the AVD:
[image: AVD]

Below is the screenshot of the SDK manager:
[image]

Could someone guide me on this issue?

Comment: go to `DDMS`(in top menu) -->LogCat(window in bottom of DDMS) and read detail of this error

Comment: Could you share the logcat messages?

Answer (score 0):

You have selected the `Nexus-5` phone resolution for the emulator with `Android-TV` system-image.

So, you need to select the corresponding resolution for `Android TV` in `Device`.

Also, select the `dynamic-hardware-control` in `Skin`.